# AutoComplete uses different padding than standalone FormControl - shouldn't it be the same?

Tags: material-ui

I'm using for a search filter page an AutoComplete and a couple of FormControls next to each other. In theory the design of those elements should be exactly the same, but there are just a slight difference in padding that makes the AutoComplete placeholder and input appear higher than that of the FormControl. Is this an inconsistency/bug that should be fixed or is it something else?

Here is a simple example I created on CodeSandbox:
https://2go7u4.csb.app/

Thanks,
Goppi

Comment: You need to specify `size="small"` on the `FormControl` rather than on the `Input`, otherwise the size change isn't applied appropriately to the label.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. That was it.